# Possessive case and indefinite article

Tags: indefinite-article, possessives

Which is the correct way to paraphrase the sentence using the possessive case:

- Everyday at noon we have a break, which lasts fifteen minutes.

a) Every day at noon we have **a** fifteen minutes' break.

b) Every day at noon we have fifteen minutes' break.

thank you in advance for your attention to the question above.

Comment: Option b. If you want to use a, say "...a fifteen minute break".

Comment: Could you tell me, please, am I right to think that Option b. is correct, as fifteen minutes in plural, so there is no need for article?

Comment: 'Break' is singular.  "Fifteen minutes" is an adjective describing the break.

Comment: @Chenmunka yes, that's why I'm confused=\ as I thought that there should be article A as the break is singular.

Comment: *Every day at noon we have a fifteen minute break.*

Answer (score 1):

Of your two options, the correct answer is **b**: "Every day at noon we have fifteen minutes' break."

An alternative wording would be "a fifteen-minute break", but "fifteen minutes' break" is correct, too.

Answer (score 0):

A determiner answers the question "which?"

Since a possessive in front of a noun answers that question, it assumes the function of a determiner and normally "takes the place" of an article, etc.

> I took the ball - I took Sally's ball (article not needed).

When adjectives are involved, the determiner comes first, then the adjectives, then the noun.

> I took the red ball - I took Sally's red ball.

But the premise of your question is wrong.  Because this really does not make sense:

> I took fifteen minutes' break.

It does not make sense for "break" to "belong" to anything called "fifteen minutes"

However, "fifteen minutes" (plural, not possessive) can modify *break* to describe the type of break.  And you would use a determiner/article as you would without the modifier.

> I took *a* *fifteen minutes* break.

Even so, this sounds better:

> I took a fifteen minute break.

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer. But it raised more questions. I have a book on English grammar by Russian authors and it says that the use of the possessive case retains not only the meaning of belonging and possession but also measure (an hour's trip, a mile's distance). As an axample I found this article http://www.dailymail.co.uk/health/article-185715/An-hours-nap--nights-sleep.html May be the catch is that there are two variants: British and American?

Comment: You can say *an hour's trip* but you cannot say *a five hour's trip.*  You would say *a five hour trip* instead.

Comment: I thought it should be five hours' trip >_< Thanks!

Comment: Why is "fifteen minutes' break" wrong  when the following are all correct: *I gave them two weeks' notice. In two years' time. Fifty dollars' worth.*